# SQL Query: each column value is an aggergation based on a different filter on a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, aggregation

I want to get the count of rows from a table based on a specific criteria for each column in my result table. The table itself is a temporary table.

The query below is what I want to accomplish but I don't know what is the syntax to get to it:

```
WITH table1 as( a huge inner joins between different tables)

SELECT *
FROM (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value1' AND column2 > 0
    ) AS Count1,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 0
    )AS Count2,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value2' AND column2 > 0
    )AS Count3,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value2' AND column2 = 0
    ) AS Count4
) CountSummary
```

This is not the right syntax, but I am not sure how to accomplish this concept in sql server.

This is the error that I'm getting currently, if I make my second part of the query equal to: `select * from table1`

```
Msg 252, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Recursive common table expression 'table1' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator.
```

The huge inner join query can be run separately without any errors.

-------------------UPDATE--------------------------

The recursive error was due to naming 'table1' the same as a table inside the inner join query part, I got rid of that, and the error was gone. Then I tried the answers and both of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:-

```
select
    sum(case when column1 = 'value1' and column2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count1,
    sum(case when column1 = 'value1' and column2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count2,
    sum(case when column1 = 'value2' and column2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count3,
    sum(case when column1 = 'value2' and column2 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count4
from table1
```

Comment: When i try this I get this error: Recursive common table expression 'table1' does not contain a top-level UNION ALL operator

Comment: You didn't mention that table1 was a CTE...can you post the rest of your query so we can see the full story of what's going on?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that affects the solution. updated.

Comment: The error was because I named 'table1' the same as one of the tables inside the inner join. I got rid of that and your query worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
WITH table1 as( a huge inner joins between different tables)

SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count1
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value1' AND column2 > 0
    ) AS Count1,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count2
        FROM table1
        WHERE 
            column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 0
    ) AS Count2
```